# Verilog : error Reference to scalar wire 'VALUE' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue

Tags: verilog

I'm stuck with this code.  I don't understand why my `VALUE` cannot be inverted.

```
module PREDIV(
    input wire QUARTZ,
     output wire VALUE);

always @ (posedge QUARTZ)
    assign VALUE= ~VALUE;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems.

You should not use the `assign` keyword inside an `always` block.

When making a procedural assignment (those inside an `always` block), you should declare the signal as a `reg` type, not a `wire`.  This is what your error message is referring to.

For sequential logic, you should use nonblocking assignments: `<=`.

Finally, a `reg` is initialized as unknown (`X`).  You need a way to initialize `VALUE`, otherwise it will remain `X`. One way is to add a `RESET` signal.

```vhdl
module PREDIV(
    input wire QUARTZ, input RESET,
     output reg VALUE);

always @ (posedge QUARTZ or posedge RESET)
    if (RESET) begin
        VALUE <= 0;
    end else begin
        VALUE <= ~VALUE;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the code is using blocking assignment in the `always` block. 
The `always` blocks should be using only non-blocking assignments.

The code should be something like:

```
always @(posedge QUARTS)
Value <= ~Value;
```